# Getting exception "org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: No value for key remote" at JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am trying to pull from a remote repository which is hosted at bitbucket. For that I am using JGit. My code is as follow;

```
        Git git = Git.open( new File( localPath+"/.git" ) );

        PullCommand pullCmd = git.pull();
        pullCmd.setCredentialsProvider(this.credentialsProvider);
        pullCmd.setRemoteBranchName(branch);
        //pullCmd.setRemote("origin");
        pullCmd.setRemote(remoteUrl);

        PullResult result = pullCmd.call();
        //FetchResult fetchResult = result.getFetchResult();
        //MergeResult mergeResult = result.getMergeResult();
        //mergeResult.getMergeStatus();
```

But I am getting exception always,

```
    org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: No value for key remote.https://xyz@bitbucket.org/xyz/testproject.git.url found in configuration
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:266)
        at git.GitPullOperation.execute(GitPullOperation.java:37)
        at ui.MainScreen.invokeGitOperation(MainScreen.java:214)
```

Tried all answer in stackoverflow, nothing worked for me.

Any help will be great for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are seeing indicates that it is trying to read from a configuration key that does not exist. This particular key uses the remote *name*, and not the URL.

It seems that the `pullCmd.setRemote(remoteUrl);` line expects a remote name and not an URL. If you have already cloned the repository you will have a remote named `origin` by default, so instead of:

```
pullCmd.setRemote(remoteUrl);
```

Try setting the value to `origin`:

```
pullCmd.setRemote("origin");
```

Comment: Yes. Exact same.

Comment: It may be the case that your repository already has a remote set up. Try using that instead perhaps it has the name `origin`. You can check by running `git remote -v` in the repository directory, from your terminal.

Comment: I have cloned a repository in a local folder. Now I want to pull from that same repository.

Comment: In that case, by default you will have a remote named `origin`, so try using `pullCmd.setRemote("origin");` instead of `pullCmd.setRemote(remoteUrl);` and don't run the `remoteAddCommand`.

Comment: Worked. :). Thank you.

Comment: Nice. I updated the answer to remove the superflous information about adding a new remote, keeping and updating only the relevant part.